# Select users with a certain role in Kohana's auth module

Tags: php, orm, many-to-many, kohana, authentication

In the auth module, we have users and roles with a many to many relationship.

My question probably has a simple answer, but I couldn't find it by myself... How would I go about selecting only users having a certain role using ORM?
What I'd like to do is something like this:

```
ORM::factory('user')->with('roles')->where('role','member')->find_all();
```

but that does not work...

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to do this:

```
$members = ORM::factory('role', 'member')->users;
```

You take the role and find it's users, not the other way around.

Comment: aha! Thank you very much indeed!